# How to get last record on second of three joins in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL Statement:

```
Select
 PD.PKey
 , PD.PId
 , PVDR.ProID
FROM `TABLE1` PD
JOIN `TABLEFACT` FACT
       ON PD.PId = FACT.PId
JOIN `TABLE2` PVDR
       ON PVDR.ProId = FACT.AProId
```

`TABLEFACT` has the field `PDATE` which is a Date Field.

How do I filter `TABLEFACT` so the only joins coming back is just the `MAX(PDATE)` prior to connecting to `TABLE2`?

Assume MYSQL.  Thanks much!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery, also known as a derived table, like this:

```
Select
    PD.PKey
  , PD.PId
  , PVDR.ProID
FROM `TABLE1` PD
JOIN (SELECT MAX(PDate) as Pdate, PId
      FROM `TABLEFACT`
      GROUP BY PId
      ) FACT
   ON PD.PId = FACT.PId
JOIN `TABLE2` PVDR
   ON PVDR.ProId = FACT.AProId
```

This assumes you want the `MAX(PDate)` for each `PId`

If you want only the `PId` with the latest `PDate` to be returned, then use a normal subquery:

```
Select
   PD.PKey
 , PD.PId
 , PVDR.ProID
FROM `TABLE1` PD
JOIN `TABLEFACT` FACT
   ON PD.PId = FACT.PId
JOIN `TABLE2` PVDR
   ON PVDR.ProId = FACT.AProId
WHERE FACT.PDate = (SELECT MAX(PDate) FROM `TABLEFACT`)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html

```
Select
 PD.PKey
 , PD.PId
 , PVDR.ProID
FROM `TABLE1` PD
JOIN `TABLEFACT` FACT
       ON PD.PId = FACT.PId
        AND
       FACT.PDATE = (
            SELECT
                MAX(PDATE)
            FROM
                `TABLEFACT`
        )
JOIN `TABLE2` PVDR
       ON PVDR.ProId = FACT.AProId
```